# SQL Server proxy tables

Tags: sql-server

I am new to notion of proxy tables.

We have a SQL Server 2000 and there was SYBASE db which had some proxy tables.

How can I do proxy tables in SQL Server 2008 to point to SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a Synonym . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx.
You have to first link the 2000 server to your 2008 server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx.