# Proxy tables SQL Server vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, proxy, datatable

We have 2 databases and we need data to be transferred from db 1 to db 2. How can I do that (in SYBASE there are proxy tables) in SQL Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server proxy tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028334/sql-server-proxy-tables)

Answer (score 0):

I think `INSERT INTO` would be a good way to go.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(v=sql.80).aspx

First of all, you can create a linked server in your destination server to the other server.  Then you can do the `INSERT INTO`.

If you don't want to do that (or are unable), then dump the data to a file and do the very fast `BULK INSERT` to get the data into your new table.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan says just BULK INSERT the data.  Assuming both databases are on the same server then you reference the table usually as databasename.schema.tablename thus db1.dbo.table1 or db2.dbo.table1

As such you can also just create a view in the destination data to use as a 'proxy' and pull the data without actually copying it.  The view would be in db2 and be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW table1 AS SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.table1
```

Comment: Unfortunetely databases are on different servers (and might be in different LANs)